# Flatpak bitcoin-core not generating .cookie file

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-qt-setup, authentication

I'm using the version of Bitcoin-Qt 0.18.1 that comes with Flatpak. I've looked in the Bitcoin datadir, which is in `~/.var/app/org.bitcoincore.bitcoin-qt/data/` and there isn't any `.cookie` file there. This is preventing me from running Electrum Personal Server.

My Linux distro is MX Linux.

My `bitcoin.conf` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I ran `bitcoind` from Flatpak and it outputted the `.cookie` file

Answer (score 0):

The GUI does not start the RPC server by default. To make sure the RPC server is running, pass the `-server=1` flag on the command line or set `server=1` in the Bitcoin Core config file.